# How to differentiate the URL access between authenticated users in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I've set up an authentication via username-password and authorization for my Spring application using SecurityFilterChain configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            HttpSecurity http,
            BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder,
            UserDetailsService userDetailsService
    ) throws Exception{
        return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder)
                .and()
                .build();

    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext
                        .requireExplicitSave(true));
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers("/main/**").authenticated()
                .requestMatchers("/main/").anonymous()
                .requestMatchers("/", "/resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        return http.build();
    }
    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
 
}
```

Here i want to do couple things.

1. If request is sent on /main/{userId}, but user is not authenticated, i want to redirect it to /main, which will not display user private information. Is it done in this class, or in the controller?
2. If authenticated, i want a user to have access only to URL with their ID, for example, user with ID=7 can access only "/main/7/**" and not any other one, like "/main/5/**". How can i configure this?

For now i have come up with this solution:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/main")
public class MainPageController {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    @GetMapping("/{userId}")
    public String getMainPageAuthenticated(Model model, @PathVariable Long userId){
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String username = auth.getName();
        if(!Objects.equals(username, userService.findUserById(userId).getUsername())) return "error";
        model.addAttribute("username", userService.findUserById(userId).getUsername());
        return "main_page_auth";
    }
}
```

But that seems like a bad solution, can i do this in configuration?